# C# for case in string(easy)

Tags: c#

so I have this code. I need to generate a for loop that checks all the characters in the string and checks if they are all valid(So numbers from 0->7). But I don't know how to write it, I tried something but it didn't work. Here are the examples:user enters: 77, code works, user enters 99, code doesn't work, user enters 5., code doesn't work, etc..

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NALOGA1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string decToOct(int stevilo)//v mojon primere 7
        {
            string izhod = "";
            //7>0 DRŽI
            while (stevilo > 0)
            {
                //izhodi se dodeli ostanek deljenja z 8 keri se spremeni v string
                izhod = (stevilo % 8) + izhod;
                //7/8;
                stevilo /= 8;
            }
            return izhod;
        }

        static int Octtodesetisko(string stevilo)
        {

            double vsota = 0; 
            for (int i = stevilo.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {

                int stevka = stevilo[i] - '0';
                vsota += (stevka * Math.Pow(8, i));
            }

            return (int)vsota;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {



            //3 podprogram-in progress


            string prvastevilka = Console.ReadLine();



            int prvasprememba = Int32.Parse(prvastevilka);
            if (prvasprememba > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(decToOct(prvasprememba));

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Napaka");
            }


                string drugastevilka = Console.ReadLine();
                int drugasprememba = Octtodesetisko(drugastevilka);
                foreach (char znak in drugastevilka)
                {
                    if(znak!=1 || znak!=2 || znak!=3 || znak!=4 || znak!=5 || znak!=6 || znak!=7)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Napaka");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("dela :D");
                    }
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Define _works_ and _doesn't work_ clearly.

Comment: While it's technically possible to follow the program flow by just looking at the logic, it'd be REALLY helpful if you translated everything to English. Reduces the overhead by a ton for people trying to help.

Comment: you dont need to check each char; `if (znak >= '0' && znak <= '7') { //valid }` - you also currently exclude '0'

Comment: Actually this logic seems wrong if(znak!=1 || znak!=2 || znak!=3 || znak!=4 || znak!=5 || znak!=6 || znak!=7) because it will always be true isn't it?

Comment: consider `znak!=1 || znak!=2`. if `znak` is 1, then `znak!=2` is `true`. if `znak` is any number other than 1, then `znak!=1` is `true`. therefore, `znak!=1 || znak!=2` is always `true` for all values of `znak`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would take advantage of the [LINQ Enumerable.All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548541(v=vs.100).aspx) method to express this in a very concise and readable way:

```
if (str.Any() && str.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '7'))
{
    Console.WriteLine("good");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("bad");
}
```

**EDIT: No LINQ**

It's not hard to translate what the LINQ `Enumerable.All` method does to a normal loop.  It's just more verbose:

```
bool isValid = true;
foreach (char c in str)
{
    if (c < '0' || c > '7')
    {
        isValid = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (str.Length != 0 && isValid)
{
    Console.WriteLine("good");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("bad");
}
```

Comment: Ok, no liq. But what about LINQ? :)

Comment: Wow the above method works, but what about an empty string?

Comment: It depends.  What do you want to do if you have an empty string?  Do you consider that valid or not?

Comment: Invalid. Using this to convert octal numbers to base ten. But the input can only be octal numbers, so from 0->7

Comment: Well, then you just add a check for that specific case.  I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there seems to be a mistake in the line

```
if(znak!=1 || znak!=2 || znak!=3 || znak!=4 || znak!=5 || znak!=6 || znak!=7)
```

I guess it should read

```
if(znak!='1' || znak!='2' || znak!='3' || znak!='4' || znak!='5' || znak!='6' || znak!='7')
```

which should be compressed to

```
if (znak >= '0' && znak <= '7')
```

You can use linq instead of the `for` loop here like this:

```
if (drugastevilka.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '7')
    Console.WriteLine("dela :D");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Napaka");
```

But the best solution is probably to use a regular expression:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[0-7]+$");
if (regex.IsMatch(drugastevilka))
    Console.WriteLine("dela :D");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Napaka");
```

*Edit: the linq solution shown accepts empty strings, the regex (as shown) needs at least 1 character. Exchange the `+` with a `*` and it will accept empty strings, too. But I don't think you want to accept empty strings.*

Comment: @averagejoex I already guessed that. I'd prefer regex, but if your task includes to use a for loop, use at least `if (znak >= '0' && znak <= '7')` instead of testing each single case.

Answer (score 0):

You are messing up with the datatype
Can you try with below code

```
static string decToOct(int stevilo)//v mojon primere 7
        {
            int izhod = 0;
            //7>0 DRŽI
            while (stevilo > 0)
            {
                //izhodi se dodeli ostanek deljenja z 8 keri se spremeni v string
                izhod = (stevilo % 8) + izhod;
                //7/8;
                stevilo /= 8;
            }
            return (izhod.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string someString = "1234567";
        string someOtherString = "1287631";
        string anotherString = "123A6F2";

        Console.WriteLine(IsValidString(someString));
        Console.WriteLine(IsValidString(someOtherString));
        Console.WriteLine(IsValidString(anotherString));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static bool IsValidString(string str)
    {
        bool isValid = true;

        char[] splitString = str.ToCharArray(); //get an array of each character

        for (int i = 0; i < splitString.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                double number = Char.GetNumericValue(splitString[i]); //try to convert the character to a double (GetNumericValue returns a double)

                if (number < 0 || number > 7) //we get here if the character is an int, then we check for 0-7
                {
                    isValid = false; //if the character is invalid, we're done.
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) //this will hit if we try to convert a non-integer character.
            {

                isValid = false;
                break;
            }                
        }

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

`IsValidString()` takes a `string`, converts it to a `Char array`, then checks each value as such:

`Get the numeric value`
`Check if the value is between 0-7`

`GetNumericValue` will fail on a non-integer character, so we wrap it in a `try/catch` - if we hit an exception we know that `isValid = false`, so we `break`.
If we get a valid number, and it's not between `0-7` we also know that `isValid = false`, so we `break`.

If we make it all the way through the list, the string is valid.

The sample given above returns:

`IsValidString(someString) == true`

`IsValidString(someOtherString) == false`

`IsValidString(anotherString) == false`